# subprocess, выполнение системой

Tags: ffmpeg, subprocess, планировщик-задач

```
subprocess.check_output("ffmpeg -i "+file+" -ss 10 -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/crop/ { print $NF }' | tail -1", shell=True).decode().strip()

subprocess.call('ffmpeg -i '+file+' -c:v libwebp -vsync vfr -vf "select=isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t\,30),scale=-2:60,tile=5x5" '+path+'c_thumb%01d.webp', shell=True)
```

Две команды и обе не работают, если скрипт запущен системой.

Скрипт запускается системой, но по каким то причинам то ли не находит файл, толи что другое.
В ручную запускать, все работает, если система запускает, вероятно не находит файл.

При этом если прописать

```
f = open('/*********/b_t.txt','w') # открытие в режиме записи
f.write(crop)                      # запись....
f.close()                          # закрытие файла
```

И запустить системой, скрипт, файл сохраняет , а при выполнении

```
subprocess.check_output("ffmpeg -i "+file+" -ss 10 -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/crop/ { print $NF }' | tail -1", shell=True).decode().strip()
```

Не находит файл как я понимаю, так же из под системы. То есть тут что  та с  subprocess.check_output

У меня вопрос. Когда скрипт запускаем из консоли, мы видим все процессы в консоли. Как данные просессы записать в txt когда скрипт запускает систем.

Не могу понять, что мне делать, как решить данную задачу